# How can I convert QByteArray to QString with separator '-'?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new in Qt and can't find any solution in Qt libraries.
I'd like to find smth without loop usage.
Is there any way to convert `QByteArray` to `QString` with `-` between bytes?
For example:

```
QByteArray = XX1F2C5A
QString = "XX-1F-2C-5A".
```

Comment: Well, you will need a simple loop and insert. And why loop is bad?

Comment: I don't want to invent bicycle, may be there are any built-in qt tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can with [QString::replace](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#replace):

```
  QByteArray b = "XX1F2C5A";
  QString s(b);
  qDebug() << s;
  s.replace(QRegExp("(..)[^$]"), QString("\\1-"));
  qDebug() << s;
```